# Override golang profile stop in case of interrupt

Tags: go, profiling, interrupt, sigint

When I `kill -SIGINT pid` on my Golang service I have a graceful shutdown where I call the `profile.Stop`, but before I could call it I got this message: `profile: caught interrupt, stopping profiles`

I can't even call the profile.Stop because it's triggered sooner, however the grpc listen and couchbase connection shutdowns works properly.

Is there anyway I can override this malfunctioning profile stop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [`profile.NoShutdownHook`](https://godoc.org/github.com/pkg/profile#NoShutdownHook) function which controls whether the profiling package should hook SIGINT, on which to write profiles cleanly.

You may use / pass the above mentioned function as an option to [`profile.Start()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/pkg/profile#Start) if you want to disable this behavior:

```
profile.Start(profile.NoShutdownHook)
```

Starting and stopping the profiling inside a function is best done via deferred, e.g.:

```
// disable the automatic shutdown hook.
defer profile.Start(profile.NoShutdownHook).Stop()
```

If you disable the automatic shutdown hook, make sure you call `Stop()` manually in your shutdown handler properly.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.